# Replicate Date Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a razor view (MVC5) with 2 date fields (Effective Date and Action Date), I am trying to accomplish the following: the moment a date has been chosen from the date picker for Effective Date then I want that chosen date to be shown directly in the Action Date field, basically, the effective date and the action date should always be the same. What is the best and cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: _What is the best and cleanest way to accomplish this?_ What about showing us what you've attempted so far (ie: what's the code you tried)?

Answer (score 0):

I think use js is a good choice.Here is a demo:

View:

```
  <input id="Effective" type="date" />
    <input id="Action" type="date" />
    <script>
            $("#Effective").change(function () {
                $("#Action").val($(this).val());
            })
    </script>
```

Result:
[image]